# Guzzlehttp slow performance

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am making a website using Laravel 5.4 that gets data from an api using guzzlehttp. I am making 96 requests, most of them (around 94) only return a few lines of json. This makes the website very slow to load (55 seconds). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is your API in a separate server network? Unless you are in the same network, making ~100 requests is going to be slow. In addition to this, I'd question the architecture behind any app request that needs to make ~100 separate API requests. If it's really that bad, you should probably think about what is really necessary. If you're making a ton of micro-requests for similar data, you can score some easy wins by simply making an endpoint that bundles that data together.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Looked through the API references once again and found one that lets me do 1 request instead of 90.. Should have done that before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Probably most of the requests can be done in parallel. Try to use [Guzzle's async requests](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#async-requests) for that.

Comment: Didn't actually need to make 90 requests so it only takes a second to load the site now. Incase I need to make more requests in the future I'm gonna look into Guzzle's async requests, Thanks!